# GoogleSignIn Kotlin SDK

Tags: kotlin, google-signin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am developing a Kotlin Multiplatform project for two platforms: Android and iOS. And I need to implement Google SignIn for the both platforms.

Is there a GoogleSignIn Kotlin SDK for Kotlin Multiplatform?

If not, what are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing official. This is the closest thing to it: https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk